# HTC VIVE Unity C# VRTK use simple pointer and bezier pointer on the same controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality, vrtk

I am developing for the HTC VIVE on Unity with VR Tool Kit and I am trying to use on the same controller the simple pointer script and the bezier pointer script. The problem is that both script use by default the touchpad and the same event "aliasPointer" for enable or disable.

I would like to know if it is possible to use the bezier pointer for the touchpad and the simple pointer for the trigger for example ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>At the moment this isn't possible unless you change the code to listen to alternative events for activation.</strike>

But it is probably worth raising your issue on the github issues page at: https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK/issues as this may be a

In the latest version of VRTK on Github master you can now do this by creating a new script that inherits the pointer you want to override (e.g. SimplePointer) and then just override the button registration method:

https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK/blob/master/Assets/VRTK/Scripts/Pointers/VRTK_BasePointer.cs#L165

You can then register whichever buttons you want to activate and set the pointer.